# In which stargate episode did they discover Naquadah?

Tags: stargate, technology, episode-identification

I saw in the Stargate:SG1 series that they encounter and use Naquadah related items very often. Humans seems very knowledgeable about it.

I would like to know in which episode did they discovered Naquadah itself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Naquadah](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Naquadah) is first discovered in the feature film. In fact, the Stargate, discovered in Giza in 1912, is made of naquadah. So technically the mineral was first discovered then.

The first episode in which naquadah is heavily-referenced is the episode "[Learning Curve](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Learning_Curve_(episode))," which features Samantha Carter working with an Orbanian child named Merrin to develop a working [naquadah generator](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Naquadah_generator). The first episode to use the word 'naquadah' (and, incidentally, establish that it is the material the Stargate is constructed from) is "[Singularity](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Singularity)." The first mention of the Tau'ri operating their own naquadah mines is in "[Enemy Mine](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_Mine_(episode))." It was established as far back as "[Need](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Need_(episode))" that the Goa'uld mined naquadah.

Comment: The film calls it an "unknown mineral," IIRC.

Comment: Yes, the film refers to it first as an 'unknown mineral' and is then later referenced by Ra, who states he is sending a shipment of 'my mineral' along with the nuclear device brought by the humans, along with the information that it would amplify the destructive impact of the bomb 100 fold(IIRC).